# how to adjust installer path in JSON file to customize vendor dir

Tags: 8, composer

Before using 'composer install' I edit extra installers paths. Example: edit /web to /a-custom-docroot folder where is placed core, modules and all other folders.

When possible I would like to create a path for my vendor dir. To create a structure like this:

'- projectroot
--docroot/core
--customdir/vendor'

Comment: I don't think this is a drupal related question. It's more like composer 100%.

Comment: Its 100% Composer but in D8 its related to Drupal. /vendor is the standard path but you can create a soft link to change the physical path.